# Flutter DataTable - How to Remove a Row onTap

Tags: flutter, datatable

I am trying to remove a DataTable's DataRow using onTap. Here is my code, but the same is not working:

```
List<DataRow> dataRows = [];
    final formatter = NumberFormat('#,##0;(#,##0)');
    for (int z = 0; z < widget.data.length; z++) {
      String cellValue = '';
      dataRows.add(
        // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
        DataRow(
          cells: [],
        ),
      );
      int ii = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++) {
        ii = i + 1;
        if (columnTypes[i] == 'N') {
          cellValue = formatter.format(double.parse(widget.data[z]['col$ii']));
        } else {
          cellValue = widget.data[z]['col$ii'].toString();
        }
        String someString = cellValue;
        dataRows[z].cells.add(
              DataCell(
                Text(cellValue),
                onTap: () => {
                  setState(() {
                    //dataRows.remove(dataRows[z]);
                    dataRows = List<DataRow>.from(dataRows)..removeAt(z);
                  }),
                },
              ),
            );
      }
    }
```